# Compiling GLFW manually "No supported window creation API selected"

Tags: c++, compilation, glfw

I'm trying to compile GLFW by including GLFW sourcecode directly into my project (no lib or dll)
and compile it.

Here is the simple example i did to try it :

```
#include <iostream>

#define _GLFW_WIN32

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

All path defined in glfw3.h is correct, and as you can see I have defined macro _GLFW_WIN32
(According to https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.1/compile.html)
However, when I compile, I got this error :

> C:\GLFW\code\internal.h (194): fatal error C1189: #error:  "No supported window creation API selected"

when looking at internal.h(line 183) :

```
#if defined(_GLFW_COCOA)
 #include "cocoa_platform.h"
#elif defined(_GLFW_WIN32)
 #include "win32_platform.h"
#elif defined(_GLFW_X11)
 #include "x11_platform.h"
#elif defined(_GLFW_WAYLAND)
 #include "wl_platform.h"
#elif defined(_GLFW_OSMESA)
 #include "null_platform.h"
#else
 #error "No supported window creation API selected"
#endif
```

Which makes no sense since I defined _GLFW_WIN32.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, using #define macro is not enough since glfw will be compiled before my main code.

The way I solve it is by using the

> -D _GLFW_WIN32

symbol in the compilation command line